# Получение пути до игры через реестр c#

Tags: c#, реестр, steam

Пытаюсь получить где установлена игра из Steam, путем доставания пути из Реестра. Код в выдает ошибку: Необработанное исключение: System.NullReferenceException: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

```
using (var lmRegistry = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32))
{
    var steamRegistry = lmRegistry.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Steam App 4000", false);
    string readypath = steamRegistry.GetValue("InstallLocation").ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(readypath);
}
```

Comment: А помоч с чем? ваш код не делает того  что нужно?(тогда что он делает?) Ваш код не компилируется или падает с ошибкой?(с какой?)....

Comment: Код выдает ошибку:
Необработанное исключение: System.NullReferenceException: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.
   в ConsoleApp3.Program.Main(String[] args) в D:\Source\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp3\Program.cs:строка 19
Может ли такое быть что нет каких то прав в реестре?

Comment: Что за код находится на строке 19? нам отсюда не видно :) приходится гадать что это строка с ```RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey``` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего вы запускаете код в 64-битной ОС, и обращаетесь к ключу 64-битной программы в реестре (т.к. 32-битные программы в 64-битной винде лежат немного по другому пути: `HKLM\Software\WOW6432Node`).

Для доступа к нужной ветке Вам нужно указать `RegistryView.Registry64`:

```
using var lmRegistry = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
using var steamRegistry = lmRegistry.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Steam App 4000", false);
string readypath = steamRegistry.GetValue("InstallLocation").ToString();
Console.WriteLine(readypath);
```

Если `lmRegistry.OpenSubKey(...)` всё равно будет возвращать `null`, попробуйте  зайти в Проект -> Свойства -> Сборка -> Целевая платформа и выберите `Any CPU`, либо просто откройте файл проекта и добавьте:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Или просто тупо собрать проект под x64

Comment: Спасибо, я добавил проверку какое значение дает null и на основе этого выполняется код